# HTMX Trigger events to post data on clicking "Enter Key" or it's alternate methods

Tags: thymeleaf, htmx

I need to trigger to fire an ajax call on clicking enter key. I tried using

```
<form class="align-items-center row" th:action="@{/addTask}"
            method="post" th:object="${formData}" hx-post="/todo/addTask"
            hx-include="#pageSize" hx-target="#result" hx-swap="innerHTML"
            hx-trigger="click[enterKey]">
            <div class="col-auto">
                <label>Item :</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
                <input id="task" type="text" class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Tasks..." th:field="*{task}" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

But it didn't worked

I need a HTMX to trigger ajax call on clicking enter key

Comment: try `keyup[enterKey]`

Answer (score 5):

keyup[keyCode==13]

worked for me, this page can help: https://www.toptal.com/developers/keycode/enter.

and this page describes how to chain events and properties, but indeed htmx validation errors could be improved ;)

https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-trigger/ --> main explanation here.

https://htmx.org/examples/keyboard-shortcuts/ ---> examples

also note that `click` is just a mouse click, wheras `keyup` or `keydown` are other events, events can be chained, or they can be triggered in sequence or alternative (see what `,` does in the above docs)